# React native crawling cheerio

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo, cheerio

I'm trying to crawl using cheerio on react native, to get the information and organize it and then put it into a ScrollView.

But when I try to print the html code of the page to see what happens and if the call is successful, nothing is printed on the console.

I'm trying directly on snack.expo.io, to be able to do some tests.

Where am I doing wrong?

Link: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/H15ImF1O4)

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import * as cloudscraper from 'react-native-cloudscraper';
import cio from 'cheerio-without-node-native';

const Item = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('ASIN:' + props.asin)}>
    <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    <Image source={{ uri: props.imageUrl }} />
    <Text>{props.price}</Text>
    <Text>{props.rating}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
    items: [],
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.loadNextPage();

  async loadGraphicCards(page = 1) {
    try {
      const searchUrl = 'https://www.amazon.it/s?k=pc&page=' + page;
      //const searchUrl = 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json';

      const response = await fetch(searchUrl); // fetch page
      const htmlString = await response.text(); // get response text
      const $ = cio.load(htmlString); // parse HTML string

      /*cloudscraper
      .get(searchUrl)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(responseHtml => {
        var x = cio.load(responseHtml);
        console.log('Urlembed:', x);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });*/

      console.log('h:', htmlString);

      console.log('s:', $('#s-result-list'));

      return $('#s-result-list') // select result <li>s
        .map((_, li) => ({
          // map to an list of objects
          asin: $(li).data('asin'),
          title: $('h2', li).text(),
          price: $('span.a-color-price', li).text(),
          rating: $('span.a-icon-alt', li).text(),
          imageUrl: $('img.s-image').attr('src'),
        }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  loadNextPage = () =>
    this.setState(async state => {
      const page = state.page + 1;
      const items = await this.loadGraphicCards(page);
      return { items, page };
    });

  render = () => (
    <ScrollView>
      {this.state.items.map(item => (
        <Item {...item} key={item.asin} />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  /*container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },*/
});
```

Comment: What are you getting back from your fetch? What is your response data? Your return code is 200?

Comment: the call is loadGraphicCards (), I don't understand if a problem with async and wait.
But if I call it I replace it with https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json, something comes back even if it's json.

Comment: The async/await part seems fine. I am wondering what you get back from `await fetch(searchUrl)`. Maybe it is a bad response or something.

Comment: With expo, the link I put you can try it directly.